# Regex to extract value from a simple JSON Object

Tags: java, json, regex

I'm looking to extract values from this JSON based on key without any JSON libraries. I figure it can be done in regex, just don't know how. All values are integers.

```
{"key1":11,"key2":2877,"key3":666,"key4":2906}
```

I want to return for example, the integer 11, if I give key1 as the input to my method.

```
public String valueFromKey(String key, String json) {
    String result = null;
    String patternStr= "Some regex with " + key;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json);

    while (matcher.find())
        result = matcher.group(1);
    }

    return result;
}

// elsewhere..
String numStr = valueFromKey("key1", "{\"key1\":11,\"key2\":2877,\"key3\":666,\"key4\":2906}");

if (numStr != null)
    int val = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
```

Comment: Any reason why you do not want to use deserialize json?

Comment: Why not use a JSON parser instead?

Comment: there may be constrained execution environments where no JSON parser is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I would just use a JSON parser.**

Having said that, you've said:

- You don't want to
- All the values will be integers

**If** we add to that another major assumption:

- The JSON will be in its minimal form, not formatted (no spaces around the `:` between property names and values)

Then yes, it's possible, with a fairly simple regular expression:

```
"key1":(\d+)
```

Since Java doesn't have regex literals, the string for that has some backslashes in it for characters we need to use that are special in string literals (specifically, `"` and `\`):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"key1\":(\\d+)");
```

That defines a match for the literal string `"key1":` followed by one or more digits, and defines the digits as a capture group. Here's an example in JavaScript:

```js
var json = '{"key1":11,"key2":2877,"key3":666,"key4":2906}';
var match = /"key1":(\d+)/.exec(json);
console.log(match ? "Got " + match[1] : "No match");
```

I **don't recommend it**, but with those assumptions, it's possible.

Comment: In My use case, its like `faq123:faq826, faq1665:faq1665, faq321:faq1665` so i use last `exec` snippet and its working. what you suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

It is best to use Json Parser, but if you insist:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        String.format("\"%s\":\s([0-9]+)", key)
    );
```

Here I assume the values are only digits and there can be a whitespace between the key and the value.

Other option is to use `split` and a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String keyValue: json.split(",")) {
    String[] data = keyValue.split(":");
    map.put(
        data[0].replace("\"", """),
        Integer.valueOf(data[1].trim());
    );
}
```

And later you just do `map.get(key)`.

Comment: For String values use `String.format("\"%s\"\\s*:\\s*\"((?=[ -~])[^\"]+)\"", id_field)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you'd want to do this at all when you can parse the JSON using a parser but here it goes.

```
String patternStr= key + "\":(\\d+)";
```

Regex will be `key`+`\":(\d+)"` based on the input string you've shown us.

**USE A JSON PARSER**, though.

Comment: If you are dealing with an error scenario and want to fish something like and ID out of a bad json string, this might be appropriate.