# Regex expression not working for special characters in front of String in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, regex

I have this string:

```
{"level": "INFO", "message": "89532154: phone number saved successfully."}
```

I wanted to extract just the word INFO out.

I have tried `^(\{.{10})(\w*)`, `(?<="level":\s*)"(\w*)"`

Other expressions that I have tried doesn't work.

So far, only `.*` works in Android Studio.

I'm using Android Studio 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a [**`JSON`**](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d838696f21e24cb9abf5465d62d63be6):

```
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "89532154: phone number saved successfully."
}
```

You should be able to get the `INFO` like this from `level`:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(yourcurrentjson);
String levelOutput = obj.getString("level");

// level output should return the INFO
```

And this with `regex`:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String keyValue: json.split(",")) {
    String[] data = keyValue.split(":");
    map.put(
        data[0].replace("\"", """),
        Integer.valueOf(data[1].trim());
    );
}
```

And then: `map.get(key)` for getting integers and this:

```
String.format("\"%s\"\\s*:\\s*\"((?=[ -~])[^\"]+)\"", id_field)
```

For ***getting strings*** like in your case.

**Check this out:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/37828403/4409113

Comment: Looking at it literally in a straight line so much that I forgot that its a JSON. 
Thanks for the help! The JSON parser really helps and it makes the code much more readable than the regex.

Comment: Well yes, I prefer the json parser too. However, you could use GSON too: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426642/convert-json-to-pojo).

Answer (score 1):

In your first regex you match `INFO` in the second capturing group by matching first 10 times any character in the first capturing group.

For as far as I know, Java does not allow a variable length in the lookbehind, so `\s*` does not work. Instead you could use a quantifier like `\\s{0,10}`

In this case you are better off using a json parser but if you must use a regex you might use:

```
(?<=\\{\"level\":\\s{0,10}\")\\w+(?=\")
```

[Java Demo](http://rextester.com/OLOW61391)